# Firebase InvalidPathValidation hasChild in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3

I'm currently trying to code a function which permits to know if a username is already taken or not.

I use Firebase to do that.

This is my code:

```
// Var REF_USERNAME_LIST within Api.User
var REF_USERNAME_LIST = Database.database().reference().child("username-list")

let username = "username.test"

      let ref = Api.User.REF_USERNAME_LIST
      ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
         if snapshot.hasChild(username){
            print("taken")
            return
         } else {

            print("good")
         }
      }) { (error) in
         print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

If I use the function hasChild, I can have this issue:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(hasChild:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

I would like to have the possibility to use a dot within the username.

Do you have any idea about how I could let this possibility and a function which permits to know if a username is already taken or not ?

Edit:

This is a part of the database:

[image]

NEW ARCHITECTURE:

[image]

Comment: Firebase does not allow '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'' in their keyvalues. You could easily get around this by reconstructing your databse. If you post a small snippet I can show you.

Comment: @Torewin Thanks for your answer ! And I'm really sorry but I'm not English, I don't really understand what do you mean by "snippet" :/ Is it a screenshot of the database structure ?

Comment: Yes, no worries. I should’ve just used screenshot. A snippet would be a small piece of your database because obviously I don’t need the whole structure.

Comment: Thank you :) I edited my first post with the snippet @Torewin

Comment: First just a tip you probably don’t need a lowercase version of your username because you can put everything to lower in a check. But besides that, is the username field what you’re looking for? If so then you don’t need hasChild. hasChild would be looking if you had the username key. Let me write you something that’s the most similar to your current code.

Comment: I'll actually need some more information. What is `REF_USERNAME_LIST` equal to?

Comment: Excuse me I was wrong when I posted the "User" part. It was about the username-list ... When a user sign up, its username is added to this table. And it is with this table that I'm checking if the username is taken or not. @Torewin

Comment: So doing it like that you will not be able to create a username with the period in it. If you want a username to have periods in it just reverse the key-values. I will post an answer so can see it easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
let ref = Api.User.REF_USERNAME_LIST
      ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
         if snapshot.value is NSNull{
             //handle null error
         }
         else{
             if let usernameList = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                                             //or [String: String]
                  for keys in usernameList.allKeys{
                      if (usernameList.getObject(for: keys) as! String == testUsername){
                           //username exists
                      }
                  }
             }
         }
      }) { (error) in
         print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Than you for this answer ! I'm trying to use your method. (I edited the question with the new architecture -> %autoId% : %username%). Now, I don't really know how I could check if the user is already taken or not .. Do you know how I could do that without hasChild ?

Comment: Of course. Very simple. Let me get to the computer in about 15 minutes and I’ll update my answer to reflect your new question. Very easy :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was calling `removeAllObservers()` method on an empty child